# Comparing strings that user input

Tags: c

I really have problem with strings. *If* function wont work and it is printing from *else*. Why?

```
    char trenutni;
    //more code
    printf("Unesite polje koje zelite da otvorite!\n");
    scanf("%c",&trenutni);

if(trenutni=='a1' && a1otvoreno!=0)
{
strncpy(a1, "koordinate", sizeof(a1));
printf("A1 je %s", a1);
printf("Da li zelite da pogadjate? Unesite slovo kolone, za konacno R ili ako ne zelite upisite 0!\n");
scanf("%c",biranje);
brojodigranih++;
a1otvoreno--;
    if(biranje=='A')
    {
    printf("Unesite resenje za kolonu A:\n");
//more code
else
printf("Vec ste otvorili to polje!\n");
```

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: This code appears to have several syntax errors and indentation problems. It'd be a lot easier to help you if you could provide a clean example that compiles.

Comment: @MaxCarroll: Croatian in the strings, C in the source code.

Comment: One of `scanf("%c", biranje);` and `if (biranje == 'A')` is wrong - and a good compiler should be complaining.  Most likely, you need `&biranje` in the `scanf()` call, or you might need `*biranje` in the `if` condition.

Comment: typically it is better to post short code but which can be used to reproduce problem, instead of code littered with "more code" remarks

Comment: @Giorgi Code have 16 if's inside this major one. Every if inside have about 300 lines of code. Maybe pastebin? Problem is that it wont compare "trenutni" string that user have input in scanf with "a1".

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh, I know that, I just didn't saw that. Thank you!

Comment: @Slay29: if you have if's indented 16-deep, you're probably not treating the problem correctly.  That is a sign of trouble.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I cannot use switch because strings.

Comment: There must be a better way, even so...maybe a table of strings and functions to call, maybe other things.  But what you describe is a code smell.

Answer (score 3):

This seems suspicious:

```
trenutni=='a1'
```

Typically you should put a single character inside single quotes `''`.

NB: [According to the standard](http://scarff.id.au/blog/2009/c-multi-character-character-constants/): "The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g., `'ab'`), [...] is implementation-defined."